# What am I missing in this simple android code?

Tags: android, multithreading

I was trying to do something else but kept on removing code thinking that simplifying things will help in identifying my mistake. This is what I am left with (after a lot of simplification) and still I am not getting it why it is not doing it is supposed to!

```
public class MyOwnTimerActivity extends Activity {

    int timeLeft = 5;
    TextView timerTextView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button timerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    timerTextView.setText("something");
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Error: The application crashed after 3 seconds i.e. after timer goes off.

Comment: And what does it suppose to do?

Comment: CHange the "timerTextView" to "something" after timer goes off. It it defined something else in main.xml

Comment: What was the error message when the application "crashed"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, yes)) This is because you try to modify UI from non UI-thread

## Update:

There are several ways to modify UI from another thread:

Using `Handler` class with overriding `handleMessage()` method

Using `Activity` class with calling `runOnUI()` method, passing there `Runnable` object in which `run()` method you modify UI

Using `View.post()` or `View.postDelayed()` methods

The last variant is the most convenient in your case. Modify your code in such manner:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button timerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    timerTextView.postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
           @Override
           run() {
               timerTextView.setText("something");
           }
        }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: @AyushGoyal: Agreed. You cannot modify the user interface from a background thread, such as the `Thread` you are using. Please switch to using an `AsyncTask`, or perhaps use `runOnUiThread()`, so that your `setText()` call can be done on the main application thread.

Comment: Got it. Didn't know that..just learned how threads work so was messing around. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to change UI from worker threads. Use a Handler, initialized on the main thread, with an ad-hoc Runnable to execute the setText() on the main thread.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Thread timer = new Thread() { 
//...
    finally
    {
         h.post(new Runnable(){
             public void run()
             {
                 timerTextView.setText("something"); 
             }
         });
     }
```

In fact, the whole snippet can be rewritten using Handler.postDelayed(). But you'll probably want to do more interesting things with a thread eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using runOnUI to set the Text from the UI thread? You can do so like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() 
    { 
        timerTextView.setText("something");
    } 
 });
```

Keep in mind, your reference to timerTextView and whatever text you want displayed would have to be modified as a final variable in order to reference it from another thread.